# Generalization of groups of the form (R-{0}, regular multiplication)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

**Result:** Fix $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(\mathbb{R} \backslash \{a\}, *)$ is a group, where our group operation is defined by $x*y = (x-a)(y-a) + a$.

One consequence of this is the standard fact that the set of nonzero real numbers forms a group under regular multiplication. (Just pick $a = 0$.)

As another, slightly more interesting option, we could let $a = -1$. Then we have the group $(\mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1\}, *)$, where the group operation is defined by $x*y = x + y + xy$.

**My question:** Has anyone seen this result (or a generalization of it) elsewhere?

It may already exist as an exercise in an Abstract Algebra text, but I suspect this particular type of group is really a specific instance of something far more general. Any references or remarks on its generalization would be most welcomed.

Comment: If memory serves, I’ve seen the case $a=1$ quite a few times as a problem in a textbook or (occasionally) contest.

Comment: First, in your third line you surely meant "the set of positive integers", and second: how does this follow from choosing $\,a=0\,$ and then taking $\,\Bbb R -\{0\}\,$ in your construction? **Added** I think I get it: you surely meant "the non-zero real numbers", right?

Comment: Right, nonzero real numbers; sorry for the typo!

Comment: I think these are called isotopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of these groups is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\},\cdot)$, via the isomorphism $\varphi(x)=x-a$. To see this, note that $\varphi$ is clearly bijective and $\varphi(x*y)=\varphi((x-a)(y-a)+a)=(x-a)(y-a)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$. Thus all their properties are the same as $(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ up to a translation by $a$.

Comment: Thanks; in retrospect this is so clear that I'm embarrassed at having asked!